# My arduino variable for server name is not seen inside the connect() call

Tags: c++, json, arduino, mqtt, adafruit

I have this running on an esp8266 but I suspect it's a c/c++ issue, most likely with me not understanding something basic.

I'm trying to connect to a mqtt server set by a value read from a json config file. Debug of the connect() call doesn't see the value I've assigned to the variable. The connect call is failing as the server name to connect to is blank, but only inside the connect() call.

What's the proper way to do this type of call?

Code snippet:

```
Adafruit_MQTT_Client *mqtt;
const char* _MqttServer = NULL;


setup {
// ...
// read file, parse json, gets the correct value
_MqttServer = jObject["mqttserver"];

// port/username/key are setup as #define earlier
mqtt = new Adafruit_MQTT_Client(&client, _MqttServer, MQTT_SERVERPORT, MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_KEY);

while ((ret = mqtt->connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
  Serial.println(mqtt->connectErrorString(ret));
  Serial.println(_MqttServer); // prints correct value
  mqtt->disconnect();
  delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
}
// ...
}
```

The error printed is from

```
bool Adafruit_MQTT_Client::connectServer() {
  // Grab server name from flash and copy to buffer for name resolution.
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  strcpy((char *)buffer, servername);
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to: ")); Serial.print((char *)buffer);
```

The error I get is

```
Connection failed!
Connecting to:
Connect result: 0
Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...
```

If I change the _MqttServer to a #define and remove it from assignment to the json it connects normally. I've done that in the meantime to get the device working. The issue I'm seeing is the passing or the assignment of the variable that is not being seen by the called function.

Comment: This is C++ not C. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to be more specific regarding whatever it is you are having a problem with. Is the `connect` call failing?

Comment: Edited with more info and corrected tags

Comment: Always post any error strings you get when you run your program. In fact, post all of the relevant output (obfuscating any secrets of course).

Comment: Added more info

Comment: I wonder if this a character encoding issue? Are you sure the json file is saved as UTF-8 no-BOM?

Comment: It happens even if I set the value manually in the function that reads the json file.